# Rear Brakes Squeaking

Tags: brakes, yaris

Got drum brakes on the rear.

They were squeaking about 5 months ago, got them cleaned and lubed and have been silent up until recently where they squeak quietly every now and again.

Car has done 77,000 miles, not sure how long the rear brake shoes have been on there for though.

IS it likely I just need to get them cleaned and lubed, or replace the shoes ?
Got a full service coming soon so hopefully the mechanics can inspect and let me know

thanks

Comment: Squeaking when the brakes are applied? Squeaking when the brakes are not being applied? Please also identify the manufacturer, model, and year of your vehicle.

Comment: Yaris MK2 2008
Squeaks every  now and again when braking to a complete stop ( just before the car stops )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Odd brake squeak only at the very end of the stop](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/2566/odd-brake-squeak-only-at-the-very-end-of-the-stop)

Comment: Sort of. I have tried lots of hard brakes from 55mph etc as the front pads are new and needed to be bedded in. So unlikely to be that.

Comment: You may also find useful suggestions in [this Question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/39808/how-should-i-troubleshoot-drum-brakes-that-squeal-during-forward-travel-but-not?rq=1).

Comment: Mechanic cleaned and lubricated the rear drums. Noise still there, and now it has started doing it when driving ( without the brakes being applied ) every now and again. IF I apply the brake it stops squeaking.
I'm going to get the shoes replaced in the drum, hopefully that sorts it